# How to receive SocketIO events in React while using states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, use-effect, use-state

This is part of my code, what I want to do is this component at any time can receive a message on any of the conversations. Sending a message triggers a Socket event which triggers this code below, but I can't seem to get the "latest" conversations, as the useEffect only triggers when the component mounts (at that point my conversations array has zero length).

What I was thinking is that I should include "conversations" on the useEffect's dependency but that would create multiple websocket connection, one each time a Socket.io event is triggered because it does change the state. Is this the best solution? Thanks in advance!

```
const [conversations, setConversations] = useState<Array<Conversations>>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function getConversations() {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("/api/conversations/");

        if (data.success) {
          setConversations(data.details);
        }
      } catch (err) {}
    }

    getConversations();

    socketInstance.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connecting to Sockets...");
      socketInstance.emit("authenticate", Cookies.get("token") || "");
    });

    socketInstance.on("ackAuth", ({ success }) => {
      console.log(
        success
          ? "Successfully connected to Sockets"
          : "There has been an error connecting to Sockets"
      );
    });

    socketInstance.on("newMessage", (data) => {
        const modifiedConversation: Conversations = conversations.find(
      (conv: Conversations) => {
        return conv.conversationId === data.conversationId;
      }
    );

    modifiedConversation.messages.push({
      from: {
        firstName: data.firstName,
        lastName: data.lastName,
        profilePhoto: data.profilePhoto,
        userId: data.userId,
      },
      content: data.content,
      timeStamp: data.timeStamp,
    });

    const updatedConversations = [
      ...conversations.filter(
        (conv) => conv.conversationId !== data.conversationId
      ),
      modifiedConversation,
    ];

    setConversations(updatedConversations);
    });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While attaching and removing the socket listeners every time `conversations` changes is a possibility, a better option would be to use the callback form of the setters. The only time you reference the state, you proceed to update the state, luckily. You can change

```
socketInstance.on("newMessage", (data) => {
  const modifiedConversation: Conversations = conversations.find(
  // lots of code
  setConversations(updatedConversations);
```

to

```
socketInstance.on("newMessage", (data) => {
  setConversations(conversations => {
    const modifiedConversation: Conversations = conversations.find(
    // lots of code
    setConversations(updatedConversations);
```

You should also not mutate the state, since this is React. Instead of

```
modifiedConversation.messages.push({
```

do

```
const modifiedConversationWithNewMessage = {
  ...modifiedConversation,
  messages: [
    ...modifiedConversation.messages,
    {
      from: {
        // rest of the object to add
```